# Install WSO2 ESB and Api Manager server in one server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have to install both WSO2 ESB and API manager server in same development server. But always get Port already in use exception. I think that caused by the two apps using same JVM.

Could anyone please shed me light on proper configuration to make two server working tighter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run multiple WSO2 products/clusters or multiple instances of the same product on the same server or virtual machines (VMs), you must change their default ports with an offset value to avoid port conflicts. An offset defines the number by which all ports in the runtime (e.g., HTTP/S ports) will be increased. For example, if the default HTTP port is 9763 and the offset is 1, the effective HTTP port will change to 9764. For each additional WSO2 product instance, you set the port offset to a unique value. The offset of the default ports is considered to be 0.

There are two ways to set an offset to a port:

1. Pass the port offset to the server during startup. The following
   command starts the server with the default port incremented by
   3:./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=3
2. Set the Ports section of `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml`.
   E.g., `<Offset>3</Offset>`

Refer [Changing the Default Ports with Offset](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset)

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan i have ectract WSO2 6.1 EI in c drive and put these in CARBON_HOME variable now where to extarct the API Manager and how to use that.Also i used NSSM for windows service.